# opencv contour error with image format

Tags: java, opencv

I am trying to create a method to implement the contour method out of the OpenCV library but am getting an error.  I have searched the error for hours but still cannot get the code to work.  Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfInt;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;

import java.awt.Rectangle;


    public class Contour {
        private static ArrayList<Rect> getContourArea() {
            System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
            Mat color = Imgcodecs.imread("C:\\Users\\bheda\\Desktop\\Cat03.jpg", CvType.CV_8UC3);
            Mat gray = new Mat();
            Imgproc.cvtColor(color, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            Mat binarized = new Mat();
            Imgproc.threshold(gray, binarized, 100, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
            Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
            List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
            Imgproc.findContours(binarized, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
            Rect rect = null;
            double maxArea = 300;
            ArrayList<Rect> arr = new ArrayList<Rect>();
            for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
                Mat contour = contours.get(i);
                double contourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(contour);
                if (contourArea > maxArea) {
                    rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(i));
                    arr.add(rect);
                }
            }
            return arr;
        }
        public static void main(String args[]){
            // Load the library

            getContourArea();
        }    
    }
```

When I try and run this code I get the following error:

```
        OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11111
Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:11111: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor
]
    at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.cvtColor_1(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.cvtColor(Imgproc.java:1858)
    at test.Contour.getContourArea(Contour.java:30)
    at test.Contour.main(Contour.java:52)
```

I have tried to convert the image to binary but it still does not work.  I'm not sure what part of the code is wrong but I followed the instructions on the OpenCv website.  The idea is implement the countour operation on a predefined image.

Comment: yes, i just modified the error can you help me with the new error?

Comment: The error message says that you're using `findContours` on something that is not a single-channel (i.e. grayscale) 8bit image. That's true, since you're calling it on `image` which is a cone of the original 3-channel `color` image you loaded. | You already have a conversion to grayscale in your code, but for some reason you never use the result (nor do you use the result of the threshold operation).

Comment: How do I use the conversion to greyscale inside the findcontours method?

Comment: You already have all the steps in there, as well as the necessary intermediate variables, you just haven't connected the pieces together correctly. The `threshold` should be done on the grayscale image you've generated earlier, and the `findContours` should use the binarized image (which is grayscale, but only with values 0 and 255 -- that's what `threshold` creates).

Comment: I tried to put the binarized imaged in the findContours as follows:
Imgproc.findContours(Imgproc.threshold(color, binarized, 100, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY), contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

it says findContours method should take Mat type and not double. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: That's not right, the functions use output parameters instead of returning something. The structure of the code you've shown is correct, you just need to replace the first parameter of the two functions in question (`threshold` and `findContours`) with the correct variable -- the one that you calculate in the preceding step.

Comment: e.g. `Imgproc.cvtColor(color, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);` -- that takes `color` image as input, and calculates `gray` image as output. Now, in the next step, when you do threshold, you want to do it on the grayscale image...look at what you do currently, you're doing it on the colour image, ignoring what you just did in the previous step.

Comment: Mat gray = new Mat();
            Imgproc.cvtColor(color, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            Mat binarized = new Mat();
            Imgproc.threshold(gray, binarized, 100, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
            Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
            List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
            Imgproc.findContours(binarized, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

Comment: i got the following error:

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11111
Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:11111: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor
]

Comment: The code pasted in comments is really hard to follow. Can you please [edit] the question, and append what you attempted and how the current code/errors look?

Comment: I just reposted the new code with the new error

Comment: `CvType.CV_8UC3` as a parameter to `imread` doesn't make sense. Remove that, by default the image will be loaded as BGR. Other than that, the code seems reasonable...

Comment: it worked !! thanks so much for your help